# Combining two ffmpeg commands

Tags: ffmpeg

At the moment, I managed to achieve my goal by issuing these two commands:

```
ffmpeg -y -f ogg -i pipe:0 -c:a libfdk_aac tmp.m4a
ffmpeg -y -i tmp.m4a -i ${PATH_DIR}cover.jpg -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 mpeg -disposition:v:0 attached_pic -metadata title="${title}" -metadata album="${album}" -metadata artist="${artist}" "${fname}"
```

How to combine them into one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your first command is about the audio then this modified second command should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -y -f ogg -i pipe:0 -i ${PATH_DIR}cover.jpg -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v:1 mpeg -disposition:v:0 attached_pic -metadata title="${title}" -metadata album="${album}" -metadata artist="${artist}" "${fname}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the ffmpeg output from one command to the other:

```
ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -f mpeg pipe:1 | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 example.mov
```

`-f` defines the format of the stream and `pipe:1` sends the output to the pipe.

In the second command xou van accept the input via `-i pipe:0`.